# Magento 2: Product's main image not able to display

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have uploaded some products with images manually before 2 days. But product images are not displaying now at back end as well as front end.

Wired thing is that thumbnail image displays properly in back end grid and front end list page but some what how I don't know product main image not displaying.

I have tried reindex, disabled cache and also checked in db as well as folder, images are there.

Please let me know if you have any solution to resolved this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command ? also check your browser console is it showing not found for images?

Comment: Yes already tried content deploy command and also checked in console, but magento display placeholder image when product main image was not found.

Comment: okay. Go to the `pub/media/catalog` and check images is there or not ? if its showing placeholder then no images is there in that folders  check and post here is there or not ?

Comment: Dear I have checked product image are already there in folder as well as in db.

Comment: refer this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422481/magento-images-not-showing-on-front-end may be it will solve your problem. Also check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990380/magento-product-upload-images-not-appearing

Comment: Reviewed that solution but didn't got proper solution and it is for magento 1 not for magento 2.

Comment: @Nits, I also facing the same problem, programmatically I have updated the product images, the small and thumbnail are showing. but in product detail page instead of the main image, it's showing Magento default images.

Comment: I fixed the issue, kindly refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191397/magento-2-image-is-not-showing-on-product-detail-page