# Magento 2 : Image is not showing on product detail page

Tags: magento2, product-images, frontend

I have created a product programmatically, and products are uploading successfully but image is not displaying on product detail page here a screen shot.
[image]

but image is also showing on homepage and admin area..heres a screeshot
[image]

[image]

admin area showing the product image too, but not in the detail page?
please suggest a solution.

Comment: NO hide from product page option is not checked

Comment: then check your browser console , is it showing not found error ? might be its permission issue

Comment: customer/section/load/?sections=compare-products%2Ccustomer%2Cwishlist%2Clast-ordered-items&update_section_id=false&_=1504175276413 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: this is the 404 not found but i dont think its for Image error

Comment: i ran the command and rewrite is already enabled

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons that could be causing this issue, for ex :

- On the Product Information page , In your admin backend, under
  'Images', make sure the radio buttons have an image selected for
  'Base Image', 'Small Image', 'Thumbnail', and that they aren't
  'Excluded'.
- Make sure the product images exist under `/media/catalog/product/`
  (relative to your document root)
- Make sure the /media directory is in your Apache web server's group.
  Magento also needs to be able to write to this directory, so you can
  run this command to set those permissions:

> ```
> sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/magento/media
> ```

- In `System->Configuration->General->Web` , make sure **"Base Media URL"** is correct under both **"Secure" and "Unsecure"**

Comment: i did all the steps u said but still not showing

Comment: Check for all browsers/ check your memory limit for php_value memory_limit 256M

Comment: Flush magento cache from admin.....If cache is enable then php bin/magento cache:clean execute this command also

Comment: already did but got nun

Comment: Rename the cache folder in media/catalog/product and refresh your website.

Comment: i did renamed the cache folder and refresh the page then product image is again moved in cache folder in and folder is created after refreshing page

Comment: but got no image in frontend

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to me i found solution, my code was `$product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_path, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'),true);`

i just added `false`, `$product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_path, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'),true,false);` at the end and that did the trick.

```
/**
     * Add image to media gallery
     *
     * @param string        $file              file path of image in file system
     * @param string|array  $mediaAttribute    code of attribute with type 'media_image',
     *                                          leave blank if image should be only in gallery
     * @param boolean       $move              if true, it will move source file
     * @param boolean       $exclude           mark image as disabled in product page view
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    public function addImageToMediaGallery($file, $mediaAttribute = null, $move = false, $exclude = true)
    {
        if ($this->hasGalleryAttribute()) {
            $this->getMediaGalleryProcessor()->addImage(
                $this,
                $file,
                $mediaAttribute,
                $move,
                $exclude
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could your mediagallery items be disabled? You can check by using a REST Client (I'm using Insomnia).

You need an API key for this. Create a new Integration in System -> Extensions -> Integrations, and activate the integration. You should receive an access token. Now prepare your REST request with the following header:

`Authorization` : `Bearer [access-token]` (fill access-token with your access token you've received.

Send a REST request to `yourmagentohost.com/rest/V1/products/{sku}/media` (filling in the sku)

You should receive a request like so:

```
[
    {
        "id": 150,
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "Hunter Boots Black",
        "position": 0,
        "disabled": true,
        "types": [
            "image",
            "small_image",
            "thumbnail"
        ],
        "file": "\/1\/1\/11.2931.003.JPG"
    },
    {
        "id": 151,
        "media_type": "image",
        "label": "Hunter Boots Brown",
        "position": 1,
        "disabled": true,
        "types": [],
        "file": "\/1\/1\/11.2931.003-1.JPG"
    }
]
```

If `disabled` is `true` here, then you need to make sure to set it to `false` when creating the product programatically.